# python regex parse using re.sub() with multiple posibilities

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the numeral content embedded in a string. The string has three possible forms:

1. 'avenue\d+', where \d+ is a number with one or more digits
   or
2. 'road\d+'
   or
3. 'lane\d+'
   I tried:

```
re.sub(r'(?:avenue(\d+)|road(\d+)|lane(\d*))',r'\1','road12')
```

This code works well for the first line below, but incorrectly for the second.

```
re.sub(r'(?:avenue(\d+)|road(\d+)|lane(\d*))',r'\1','avenue12')
Out[81]: '12'
re.sub(r'(?:avenue(\d+)|road(\d+)|lane(\d*))',r'\1','road12')
Out[82]: ''
```

what am I doing incorrectly?
thanks
i

Comment: So, if you have strings "avenue", "lane", or "road" followed by any number of digits, you want to extract the digits?

Comment: The capturing group that participated in the match was  different, so use `r'\1\2\3'`. Also, the non-capturing group is superfluous, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The capturing group that participated in the match was  different. In the first case, it was Group 1, in the second case, it was Group 2.

Also, note that the non-capturing group is superfluous, remove it.

To fix the immediate issue, you can use `r'\1\2\3'` as replacement:

```py
re.sub(r'avenue(\d+)|road(\d+)|lane(\d+)',r'\1\2\3','road12')
```

However, it seems extracting is much simpler here:

```py
m = re.search(r'(?:avenue|road|lane)(\d+)','road12')
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1e8mr/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:avenue|road|lane)` - either `avenue`, `road`, or `lane`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

Comment: I see that he has `\d*` next to `lane` - probably he wants to match `lane` without number too. Now it must have a number.

Comment: @AndrejKesely There is no way OP needs an empty result when extracting data.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? The part that changes, avenue, road or lane can go in the non capturing group, then get the following number:

```py
re.sub(r'(?:avenue|road|lane)(\d+)',r'\1','road12')
```

Comment: This answer by mjsqu works, and so does the answer by Wiktor. Thank you both. However, in my real code the numeral pattern is different for each "road/avenue/..) something like this:  avenue is numbered 12-24 while road us numbered 23-44_34 etc. So I really would like a way to have the text and numeral decoded together. Wiktor's solution will do this. the only question in my mind is why areall the three groups captured even if they do not match?

Comment: All three groups are not captured. Refer to your original code in the Regex 101 demo here: https://regex101.com/r/jCeYxs/1 - For the first example with `road` only `\2` is captured, for an example with `avenue` only `\1` is captured.